# How do I use MATLAB's unit testing framework to test the number of output arguments (nargout)?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I have a method in a custom class that can only return 0, 1, or 2 outputs. I check this with `nargoutchk(0, 2)`. I'm at a loss when it comes to unit testing this method when a wrong number of output arguments are specified. This doesn't work:

```
classdef MyClassTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testMyMethod(testCase)
            verifyError(testCase, @() [x, y, z] = myMethod(5), 'MATLAB:nargoutchk:tooManyOutputs')
        end
    end

    methods
        function varargout = myMethod(a)
            nargoutchk(0, 2)
        end
    end
end
```

because MATLAB can't perform assignments inside an anonymous function. This doesn't work either:

```
classdef MyClassTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testMyMethod(testCase)
            try
                [x, y, z] = myMethod(5);
            catch ex
                verifyError(testCase, @() rethrow(ex), 'MATLAB:nargoutchk:tooManyOutputs')
            end
        end
    end

    methods
        function varargout = myMethod(a)
            nargoutchk(0, 2)
        end
    end
end
```

because `rethrow` isn't recognized inside an anonymous function (because it's not in the immediate scope of the `catch` block).

Are there any workarounds for this, or is it not possible in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily using the Throws constraint and verifyThat instead of verifyError. This can look like this:

```
classdef MyClassTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testMyMethod(testCase)
            import matlab.unittest.constraints.Throws;

            testCase.verifyThat(@() myMethod(5), ...
                Throws('MATLAB:nargoutchk:tooManyOutputs', 'WhenNargoutIs', 3));
        end
    end
end
```

Check out the [Throws](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.throwsclass.html) documentation for more info.

Another alternative is to wrap the function call you pass to verifyError into a nested or local function:

```
classdef MyClassTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testMyMethod(testCase)
            verifyError(testCase, @callMyMethodWithThreeOutputs, ...
                'MATLAB:nargoutchk:tooManyOutputs');
        end
    end
end

function callMyMethodWithThreeOutputs
[~,~,~] = myMethod(5);
end
```

Hope that helps!